# how to send multiple image to web server

Tags: android

How to send a multiple image in sd card android to web server? Two images or more?

This is my code

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg =BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/Plant/pupuk/134681282302.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
String ba1 = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", ba1));
```

I only found the way to select a single image. I can't send two or more image to web server.

Thanks for your attention. sorry for my bad english.

cheers

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would depend on what your server is expecting. If the code you posted works, you can simply iterate over it to send multiple images

Answer (score 0):

you can send with different different keys..

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image1", ba1));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image2", ba2));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image3", ba3));
.
.
```